# Changing colour of side bar dropdown for my header links on mobile

Tags: python

How do I change the colour of a dropdown menu for a mobile version of my website? When I click the three lines the background and the colour is white, how do i change it?

I tried youtube codes but it was for something else.

Comment: What framework or library are you using? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.